# Managing Logged in users

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small application I'm working on which that allows users to log in. I have about 12 pages and only logged in user can see 3 of those pages. My question is how do I manage the access so that admins can see all the pages while ordinary logged in users can see fewer of those authenticated pages?

What I'm basically asking for here is how to manage access based on permission? User logs in, they see user management page, but when someone with admin right logs in, they should have more options. Do I need to add some code in the header of all the pages or something?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

just add permission field into database and select it

```
if ($_SESSION['logged_in_user_is'] == "admin"){
   //show all of them
}
elseif ($_SESSION['logged_in_user_is'] == "normal user"){
   // show some of them
}
else{
   //she/he's unlogged, do whatever you want here
}
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion, I think this should work. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are running Apache, take a look at using htaccess files to manage authorizations: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't see anywhere on that page where it talks about managing PHP/MySql access. I'm not managing access on a network, my focus here is in web application.

Comment: Every folder in a web site can have a htaccess file that specifies which users can view which files. That works for any kind of file based access, also for accessing php files. MySQL access is usually performed from within the PHP code, so if you have admin php files that allow admin MySQL access, htaccess files could be the way to go. It is a very common way of performing authorization on an Apache based web server.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I have no idea how this works so I won't be going there at the moment. I appreciate your suggest BTW :)